# Saving manual changes to associated entities in Cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, entities

I am trying to save an entity and in the process change some properties in its associated data. I thought this would work, but it obviously doesn't:

```
$user = $this->Users->get(2, ['contain' => 'Spots']);

$user->name = "newUserName";
$user->spots[2]->name = 'newSpotName';

$this->Users->save($user);
```

The name of the users saved fine, but the spot name is not.

All the questions I have been able to find concerns form data being saved. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When manually changing associated entities (as opposed to using `Table::patchEntity()`), you must make sure that the respective property name of the association is being marked as dirty (only dirty entities/properties are being saved).

So in your case `User::$spots` needs to be dirty:

```
// ...
$user->spots[2]->name = 'newSpotName';

$user->setDirty('spots', true); // dirty() in CakePHP < 3.4
```

If the entity would be neested deeper, like `$user->foo->bar->spots`, all properties in that chain would need to be dirty:

```
$user->foo->bar->spots[2]->name = 'newSpotName';

$user->foo->bar->setDirty('spots', true);
$user->foo->setDirty('bar', true);
$user->setDirty('foo', true);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations)**

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I didn't pick that out - I have been staring at that section of the Docs all morning.

Answer (score -1):

Please refere https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations

```
$this->Users->save($user, ['associated' => ['Spots']]);
```

I hope this will work for you.

Best of luck in advance.